# Generic method for types

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Caster{

    public boolean tryCast(Object value);

}
```

and its implementations:

```
public class IntegerCaster{

    public boolean tryCast(Object value){
        try{
            Integer.class.cast(value);
            return true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            return false;
        }
   }
}
public class DateCaster{

        public boolean tryCast(Object value){
            try{
                Date.class.cast(value);
                return true;
            } catch (ClassCastException e){
                return false;
            }
       }
}
```

Is it possible to make such implementation generic? We can't quite take and declare Caster with type parameter, because we won't be able implement it as follows:

```
public interface Caster<T>{

    public boolean tryCast(Object value);

}

public class CasterImpl<T> implements Caster<T>{

    public boolean tryCast(Object value){
        try{
            T.class.cast(value); //fail
            return true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not using `Integer.class.isInstance`, `Date.class.isInstance`, etc instead of this interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to *inject* the `Class` value, parameterized by `T`, within your Generic `CasterImpl`.

Something like this:

```
public class CasterImpl<T> implements Caster<T> {

    private Clazz<T> clazz;

    public CasterImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public boolean tryCast(Object value){
        try{
            clazz.cast(value);
            return true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

As a side note: I don't see a reason why the `Caster` interface is Generic, since you don't use the type-parameter within the interface.

Comment: `tryCast(Object value)` must be written as `tryCast(T value)`

Comment: Yes, if the method signature in the interface is changed.

Comment: Actually, pretty simple. I'll do it that way.

Comment: @prashantthakre: if the object to be casted is already `T`, then what's the point of casting it to `T`?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without interface at all using standard [`Class.isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method. If you still want to implement this interface, use

```
public Caster getCaster(final Class<?> clazz) {
     return new Caster() {
         public boolean tryCast(Object value) {
             return clazz.isInstance(value);
         }
     };
}
```

Or simpler in Java 8:

```
public Caster getCaster(final Class<?> clazz) {
     return clazz::isInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generics in Java are implemented by *erasure*. Java produces a *single bytecode* for all `T`.

So this:

```
return T.class.cast(value);
```

would - if it were allowed - become essentially a

```
return Object.class.cast(value);
```

no matter which `T` you specify. If you want to check a specific class, you need a `Class<T>` object.

#### Use `someclass.isInstance(obj)` instead.

Right now, **you are *reinventing* the `Class<T>` API**.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just store the class of `T` to use later in the constructor:

```
public interface Caster<T>{

    public boolean tryCast(Object value);

}

public class CasterImpl<T> implements Caster<T>{
   private Class<? extends T> cls;
   public CasterImpl(Class<? extends T> cl) {
      this.cls = cl;
   }

    public boolean tryCast(Object value){
        try{
            cls.cast(value); //fail
            return true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instances of a generic type do not store their generic type parameter.

You can store the class as kocko said or you can store the generic type parameter inside a new type this way:

```
public abstract class CasterImpl<T> implements Caster<T>{

    public boolean tryCast(Object value){
        try{
            getValueClass().cast(value);
            return true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class<T> getValueClass() {
        Class<? extends CasterImpl<T>> c = (Class<? extends CasterImpl<T>>) this.getClass();
        ParameterizedType x = (ParameterizedType) c.getGenericSuperclass();
        return (Class<T>) x.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

That will only work with subclasses like this, that store the type in it's own type definition:

```
public class CasterIntegerImpl extends CasterImpl<Integer> {
    // No need to implement anything
}
```

Test:

```
    System.out.println(new CasterIntegerImpl().tryCast(1)); // true
    System.out.println(new CasterIntegerImpl().tryCast("")); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , use T instead of Object

```
public interface Caster<T>{

    public boolean tryCast(T value);

}


public class CasterImpl<T> implements Caster<T>{
   private Class<? extends T> cls;
   public CasterImpl(Class<? extends T> cl) {
      this.cls = cl;
   }

    public boolean tryCast(T value){
        try{
            cls.cast(value); //fail
            return true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            return false;
        }
   }
```